# How do unix domain sockets work in Erlang 19

Tags: erlang

I tried a few things but I'm not able to read anything from them

```
{ok, Port} = gen_udp:open(0, [{ifaddr,{local,"/tmp/socket2"}}]).
```

Then I switch to console.

```
echo "hi" |  socat - UNIX-CONNECT:/tmp/socket2
```

Back to erlang

```
41> gen_udp:recv(Port, 2, 5000).
{error,timeout}
```

Any help is appreciated. I've also tried {active, true} opt and flush(). shows nothing.

Comment: Does the first command even execute? It doesn't seem to be possible: http://erlang.org/faq/problems.html#idp32954192. There is some discussion and a patch for that (http://comments.gmane.org/gmane.comp.lang.erlang.patches/4775), but apparently you have to create the unix socket outside Erlang or using a NIF.

Comment: It does according to the latest release notes, this is a new thing.

Comment: Ah! I wasn't aware of this change. Is it mentioned in the changelog? Anyway I'll have a closer look.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I've not tried the official release 19, but I can make it work using the **latest git** (as of July 7th) by:

1. disabling active with `{active, false}`
2. using UNIX-SENDTO instead of UNIX-CONNECT
3. binding socat's socket to its own address (not binding creates an error on erlangs side when resolving the address.)

**Demonstration**:

console 1:

```
$ rm /tmp/socket*
$ erl
Erlang/OTP 19 [erts-8.0.1] [source-ca40008] [64-bit] [smp:2:2] [async-threads:10] [hipe] [kernel-poll:false]

Eshell V8.0.1  (abort with ^G)
 1> {ok, Port} = gen_udp:open(0, [{active, false},{ifaddr, {local,"/tmp/socket2"}}]),
 1>         io:format("ok~w ~w~n", [ok,Port]),
 1>         gen_udp:recv(Port, 2).
 okok #Port<0.451>
```

console 2:

```
 $ echo "hi" |  socat - UNIX-SENDTO:/tmp/socket2,bind=/tmp/socket1
```

console 1 results:

```
okok #Port<0.451>
{ok,{{local,<<"/tmp/socket1">>},0,"hi\n"}}
```